# How to tell if there are other keys in a hash other than specified ones?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a hash:

```
a = {b: "asdfgh", c: "qwerty", d: "dvorak"}
```

And I want to be able to tell if there are keys other than the ones I specify in it, something like this:

```
a.has_other_keys?(:b, :c, :d)
=> false
a.has_other_keys?(:c, :d)
=> true
```

But I don't want it to return false if there are LESS keys than specified:

```
a.has_other_keys?(:b, :c, :d, :e)
=> true
```

Is there an easy way to do this in ruby?

Comment: Having only a "Ruby" tag implies you want a pure Ruby solution. If a Rails solution is acceptable, your should add a Rails tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rails has an except/except! method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) that returns the hash with those keys removed. If you're already using Rails, You can use it

```
class Hash
  # Returns a hash that includes everything but the given keys.
  #   hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil}
  #   hash.except(:c) # => { a: true, b: false}
  #   hash # => { a: true, b: false, c: nil}
  #
  # This is useful for limiting a set of parameters to everything but a few known toggles:
  #   @person.update(params[:person].except(:admin))
  def except(*keys)
    dup.except!(*keys)
  end

  # Replaces the hash without the given keys.
  #   hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil}
  #   hash.except!(:c) # => { a: true, b: false}
  #   hash # => { a: true, b: false }
  def except!(*keys)
    keys.each { |key| delete(key) }
    self
  end
end
```

Using above you can do:

```
bundle :002 >    a = {b: "asdfgh", c: "qwerty", d: "dvorak"}
 => {:b=>"asdfgh", :c=>"qwerty", :d=>"dvorak"}
bundle :006 >  a.except(:b)
 => {:c=>"qwerty", :d=>"dvorak"}
bundle :007 >  a.except(:b).length
 => 2
bundle :008 >  a.except(:b, :c, :d, :e).length
 => 0
```

---

In plain Ruby, You can do something like following:

```
2.2.2 :010 >  a.select{|x| ![:b, :c, :d, :e].include?(x)}
 => {}
2.2.2 :011 >  a.select{|x| ![:b, :c, :d, :e].include?(x)}.length
 => 0
```

Comment: Not without some finagling, you wouldn't, because both `:b, :c, :d` and `:b, :c, :d, :e` return an empty set, which doesn't trivially meet the requirements.

Comment: This worked well for my purposes and seems to answer my question, thanks.

Comment: @KepoorHampond How? You get the same result for `:b, :c, :d` and `:b, :c, :d, :e`, which runs counter to your stated requirements, which requires different results.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I am equally puzzled by the OP's reply to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
def subset_of_keys?(h, other_keys)
  (other_keys - h.keys).empty?
end

h  = { b: "asdfgh", c: "qwerty", d: "dvorak"}

subset_of_keys? h, [:d, :b]
  #=> true
subset_of_keys? h, [:b, :w, :d]
  #=> false
```

See [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I just noticed Cary Swoveland's answer uses this same technique. His answer was here first.

If this doesn't have to be a high performance solution, you might consider using Array arithmetics (which a nice Ruby feature).

For example:

Your hash:

```
a = {b: "asdfgh", c: "qwerty", d: "dvorak"}
```

And our known keys:

```
known_keys = [:b, :c]
```

The rest of the keys:

```
other_keys = a.keys - known_keys
other_keys.empty?
```

For a `true`/`false` statement, we can do something like this:

```
(a.keys - [:b, :c]).empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether sets constructed from the keys are the same:

```
require 'set'

class Hash
    def has_other_keys?(*keys)
        Set.new(keys) != Set.new(self.keys)
    end
end
```

Comment: This returns `false` for the final requirement.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Ah, sorry, misread it. (Am I still misreading it? Seems like it could have been phrased much more simply if this is really what was needed.)

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, I kept overthinking the problem and this is what I was able to work it down to, sorry.

Comment: I found it confusing because to me it seems illogical--maybe I'm the one misreading it. Now OP is saying getting the same results from querying against `:b, :c, :d` and `:b, :c, :d, :e` is okay, so I give up.